# Intermittent simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning on local Joomla site

Tags: php, joomla

I've just started getting an intermittent error on all pages of a joomla dev site I'm running on localhost.

The full warning is:

`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/site/language/en-GB/en-GB.xml" in /site/libraries/joomla/language/language.php on line 1354`

The strange thing is that it is intermittent and a few refreshes will usually resolve the problem.

Is there a code problem that could be causing this or is it something else?

Comment: An intermittent `I/O warning` sounds like it could be a system/hardware issue perhaps? Maybe a full hard disk or something?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thanks for the reply, I just checked that and there is 65GB free on ssd so that isn't it. Also, it's always the same file which is strange...

Comment: Hmm. Not sure how to debug this (and get an actual useful error message instead of the pointless "I/O warning")

Comment: Race conditions for the file handler from something else?

Comment: @Zarazthuztra Thank you for your reply, would you mind explaining your suggestion as I don't understand!

Comment: @doovers When a user/thread is accessing a file, often times a "lock" is put on it to help with issues in writie/reading the file at the same time as the other, which can produce unexpected results and ambiguities. For example, two threads write to a file at the same time, whose data gets in there? What  MIGHT be happening (I know nothing about the API being used by Joomla) is that there is some sort of locking conflict, resulting in the above, whereby two threads are not configured correctly to wait for the lock to be removed before trying to access the file contents.

Comment: That's just postulating off the cuff though, I could be completely way off the mark. Haven't had to deal with that sort of scenario since my Comp Sci curriculum in college.

Comment: @Zarazthuztra Sounds like a reasonable theory to me, I'll do some research on that and see what I come up with.

Comment: Cool deal, let's fix this thing! Looking at the "Related" bar at this very moment I see someone having the same issue except with Drupal. This is why I hate CMS systems ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's early days yet to say conclusively that this fix works but it seems to have fixed it for now.

**EDIT:** Haven't seen any reoccurrence since making this change so I can confirm that this has resolved the problem.

add `libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);` to joomla's index.php

Credit goes to Corneliu on the Joomla forum for his post in this thread:

[J! 3.1.6/3.2 simplexml_load_file, JForm::getInstance errors](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=826472)

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I'm on php v5.5.3, and simplexml_load_file just wouldn't work at all, even with perfectly accessible local files. This solution worked for me.

Comment: Great info!!! Doovers, thanks for the info and the link. I ran into the same issue that killed a Magento store today, and this function saved me. My problem was also related to Piwik.

Answer (score 9):

Let me put it here just in case for somebody will google for an answer and the solution with **not thread-safe** `libxml_disable_entity_loader(false)` will not be applicable. The potential vulnerability of enabling the entity loader system-wide is shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE scan [<!ENTITY test SYSTEM 
      "php://filter/read=convert.base64-encode/resource=/etc/passwd">]>
<scan>&test;</scan>
```

The problem caused by the lack of thread safety is explained [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64938). Although one might either register her own entity loader with `libxml_set_external_entity_loader`, or use locks  to protect calls to `libxml_disable_entity_loader`, these solutions seem a bit puzzling.

The good news is that the problem with external entities affects **only** the functions dealing with **files** (e.g. [`simplexml_load_file`](https://www.php.net/simplexml_load_file), [`DOMDocument::schemaValidate`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.schemavalidate.php) and like). That makes the solution straight and simple. First load file content as string and then execute the respective libxml string-oriented function.

```
simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($xml));
```

and/or

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF8');
$xml->loadXML(file_get_contents($xmlFile));
$xml->schemaValidateSource(file_get_contents($xsdFile));
```

Hope it helps somebody.