# Intermittent Magento Errors

Tags: php, magento, session

We are having issues with our staging machine, which is running `Magento EE 1.13.1`

The problem started happening Tuesday afternoon.

At that time we updated an installed php / mysql application.

On the main magento site, the browser is redirected to the magento install page.

The problem occurs only within the Magento application and is related to sessions – when the error occurs, magento throws a fatal similar to this:

(I created a small test application to try to isolate the problem).

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getCode() on a non-object in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php on line 71

```
Call Stack: 0.0002 653728 
1. {main}() /var/www/html/t.php:0 0.3013 8153600 
2. Mage::getSingleton() /var/www/html/t.php:20 0.3013 8153912 
3. Mage::getModel() /var/www/html/app/Mage.php:477 0.3013 8153912 
4. Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance() /var/www/html/app/Mage.php:463 0.3016 8302032 
5. Mage_Customer_Model_Session->__construct() /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:1348
```

The issue only occurs intermittently, and we can temporarily fix it by stopping and starting the httpd service.

We are running magento ee 1.13.1, php 5.3.3, and httpd 2.2.15

This is happening on a staging machine. Our production machine which has the same system and code on it, it working correctly.

We have tried to turn on/off magento compiling, caching, php apc, changed the php sessions to use the disk rather than /tmp/fs, and changed magento to use the DB for its sessions.

The site fails after several minutes.

There are no errors in the system logs.

Can someone suggest how to debug this?

Comment: post your session related configuration from local.xml file.Is there any load balancer.

Comment: The local.xml is basically the same across our development, staging, and production instances, other than the security key and the DB credentials.

There is no load balancer.

Comment: set session to be stored in data base and then check if this still happens.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't make any difference. I created a very simple test web php program that loaded the ./app/etc/local.xml file and that test program failed intermittently. Our conclusion is some kind of hardware issue. Thanks for everyone's suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be an issue related to the `libxml_disable_entity_loader()` function.

The zend framework calls this function `libxml_disable_entity_loader`(true) and then calls it again with (false).

There is a path through our code that was leaving this set to true.

This setting's scope is not limited to the current php script, but to the current httpd process. I.e. it's sticky, and this prevents php's `simplexml_load_file` function from loading external files.

I came across this article:

[Intermittent simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning on local Joomla site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534866/intermittent-simplexml-load-file-i-o-warning-on-local-joomla-site)

Which led me discover that `libxml_disable_entity_loader` is not thread safe, and indeed 'sticky' within httpd processes.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Magento compilation:

```
$ php -f shell/compiler.php -- disable
Compiler include path disabled
```

There are three ways in which this can be done:

- From Magento admin
  Navigate to System → Tools → Compilation page and click on Disable button. Navigate to System → Cache Management screen and use Flush Cache button.
- Using SFTP, by editing at includes/config.php file
  To disable compilation in Magento, edit includes/config.php. Uncomment the first line and comment out the second:

  ```
  define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(FILE).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
  define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(FILE).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
  ```
- Using SSH shell program:

  ```
  php -f shell/compiler.php -- disable

  php -f shell/compiler.php -- clear
  ```