# simplexml_load_file() error is showed some every X hours

Tags: php, xml, nginx, laravel-5.1, php-7

I have an **Ubuntu 16.04 server**, there I installed **PHP7+Nginx+MySQL**. Also I have a web application developed in **Laravel 5.1** in which I take some uploaded files (by the user, they content XML) and read them, I use `xml_load_file()` to do this, in my local environment everything work great!
Then, in the server when I just cloned the project there I noticed than that function was not working, instead it returned this error:

```
simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;/tmp/phpSFeOBP&quot;
```

So, I researched and noticed that I had to enable `allow_url_fopen` in the `php.ini` file, so I did  it and restarted the server using:

```
sudo systemctl restart php7.0-fpm
```

And then it started to work great, but, something strange it happening now, every some hours the server gives the error, and I have to be restarting the `php7.0-fpm` over and over again, and the `php.ini` file is the same, it's not modified, so I don't really know what is,what should I do or even why is happening.

**To be more especific**, this is the code that I have in my project to read the file (and the file exist,so it's not the problem):

```
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 'on');//I set this to ensure,but nothin happens
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
```

Comment: Actually, no. According to the error message SimpleXML can not load the LOCAL file from the temporary directory.  Allow URLs in fopen() will not change that. The option activates the URL based streamwrappers for remote resources. The reason for your error is most likely some race condition that locks or deletes the file.

Comment: @ThW finally I managed to fix it using the answer proposed by mudasobwa in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534866/intermittent-simplexml-load-file-i-o-warning-on-local-joomla-site